# where is stdin defined in c standard library?

Tags: c, declaration, stdin, definition, standard-library

I found this line in stdio.h :

```
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdin;
```

Based on this 'extern' keyword, i assume this is just a declaration. I wonder where is stdin defined and initialized?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's defined in the source code of your C library. You typically only need the headers for compilation, but you can find the source code for many open-source standard libraries (like glibc).

In glibc, it's defined in `libio/stdio.c` as like this:

```
_IO_FILE *stdin = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdin_;
```

Which is in turn defined using a macro in `libio/stdfiles.c` like this:

```
DEF_STDFILE(_IO_2_1_stdin_, 0, 0, _IO_NO_WRITES);
```

The definition of the `DEF_STDFILE` macro varies depending on a few things, but it more or less sets up an appropriate `FILE` struct using the file descriptor `0` (which is standard input on Unix).

The definition may (and of course does) vary depending on your C library, and certainly by platform. If you want, you can continue the goose chase around the various parts of your standard library's I/O component.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard explicitly states that `stdin` is a macro defined in `stdio.h`. It is not allowed to be defined anywhere else.

C11 7.21.1

> "The header `<stdio.h>` defines several macros, ..." /--/
>
> "The macros are..." /--/
>
> **stderr**
> **stdin**
> **stdout**
>
> which are expressions of type ‘‘pointer to FILE’’ that point to the FILE objects
> associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.

This macro can of course point at implementation details that are implemented elsewhere, such as in a "stdio.c" or whatever the compiler library chose to put it.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard library code, where else? In a Linux machine around here it's in `libc.a:stdio.o`, found using `nm -o /usr/lib/libc.a | grep stdin | grep D`. If you want to read some code, see the [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's defined in `stdio.c` which is compiled into in `libc` (on gnu based systems)

Answer (score 0):

The definition will be implementation dependent, as will where you find it. For me, on OSX 10.6, it's defined in stdio.h, as a FILE (a struct).

stdin is of the type _IO_FILE, a struct which is clearly defined somewhere, probably in stdio.h. If not, check in the header files included in stdio.h for a definition of _IO_FILE.

Comment: No, that's the *declaration*.  The *definition* is in the C library source code.

Comment: I don't follow. Seems to me like FILE is defined on lines 132-163 of stdio.h on my system, where all of its members are specified. Does that not constitute definition for a struct?

Comment: @bcr: It defines the struct *type*.  It doesn't define the *object* `stdin`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Adam was referring to my second "defined"...my apologies.